# SQL: Create new column with default, unique value

Tags: default-value, ssms, unique-constraint

I have added a new column, called Ordinal, to a table called Activity. The problem is that I gave it a UNIQUE constraint, set it to allow NULL (though this I won't want in the end.. I just needed to set it to that to get a little farther with the script), and did not give it a default value. I'm now running a RedGate SQL Compare script that was generated by comparing this table to a version of the Activity table that does not have the column. But I'm getting the following error:

**The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'iwt.Activity' and the index name 'IX_Activity'. The duplicate key value is (1).**

So based on my research, it's trying to create a unique key constraint on the Ordinal column, but NULL is not unique. So my next step was to give it a unique value of 1 just to let the script pass. But 1 isn't going to be unique either. So, finally, my question:

Preferably in SQL Server Management Studio, how do I set a column as having a *unique* default value? Isn't that what I would need to create this constraint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
NULL will be the first constraint when you create the column.
UNIQUE will be as add constraint, you should add the second constraint.
they can run on this order with no problem (tested):

```
--first constraint
alter table Table_Name
add Column_Name int null

--second constraint
alter table Table_Name
add constraint Constraint_Name unique (Column_Name)
```

Comment: it didn't work with me , I got this : The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'tablenAME' and the index name 'UC_PaymentGatewayHash'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>).

Answer (score 0):

In my example :

PaymentGatewayHash is **column**

Cart is a **table**

```
--first query
alter table Cart 
add PaymentGatewayHash NVARCHAR(20) null


--second query
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PaymentGatewayHashUnique
  ON Cart (PaymentGatewayHash)
  WHERE PaymentGatewayHash IS NOT NULL
```

I just tested that :D

[image]